# com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloHttpException: HTTP 500

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

I am getting this exception using the apollo graphql client for android.

```
com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloHttpException: HTTP 500
```

I used the same query in [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download/) and it is working fine.

Here's the query:

```
query FetchAds($afterPostDate: Int, $beforePostDate: Int, $beforeUpdateDate: Int, $afterUpdateDate: Int, $page: Int, $city: String, $onlyWithImage: Boolean, $near: String, $tag: String, $id: [Int]) {
  posts(afterPostDate:$afterPostDate, beforePostDate: $beforePostDate, beforeUpdateDate: $beforeUpdateDate, afterUpdateDate: $afterUpdateDate, page: $page, city: $city, onlyWithImage: $onlyWithImage, near: $near, tag: $tag, id: $id) {
    items {
      id
      title
      postDate
      updateDate
    }
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I am also using this same query in iOS app with apollo client and it is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Error codes > 500 denote a server issue https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Server_error_responses

You can try to simplify your query or run a different query to narrow down the issue and send more info to the serer developers.